# Angular content with style and image with eventlistener do not work

Tags: angular

When loading my content from the db. After that i want to display the content in my view. The content could be like that:

```
<p><span style=\"background-color: rgb(253, 236, 217);\">STYLED TEXT</span>UNSTYLEDTEXT</p>\n<p>Das Bild: <img src=\"url"></p>
```

And insert this like that into my html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="sanitizedContent"></div>
```

And sanitize it like that:

```
  get sanitizedContent() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.beitrag?.content || '');
  }
```

The style gets displayed correctly. But the Eventlistener does not work. How do I add this when using bypassSecurityTrustHtml.

Answer (score 0):

Content rendered inside `innerHTML` is outside the Angular context, so angular events/property bindings do not work for them.

If you just want to style your content then you can use `innerHTML`, if you have events/property binding to happen, don't store the HTML in the database, just store the data and use Angular to render it dynamically with all the events/property binding set.